# JTable - filling table rows sequentially

Tags: java, swing

I have a jtable and one of cell in each row contains combobox. When i select a value from combobox then that whole row gets updated with somme values.
Now i need to fill data in sequentially manner only.
E.g
1) If user selects a combobox in first row then that row gets updated
2) Now if user selects a comobox other than second row then it should give some alert and stop editing the value

Comment: What is your problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: add `addTableModelListener` listener on `table's model`. On each update on `combobox` check previous rows values. If any one is empty or default then do nothing. Use row and column number to check for value from `model`.